# Changing TCONT802AS32DAA Thermostats to Honeywell T9 on Trane System with Honeywell HZ432

Tags: hvac, thermostat, heat-pump

I'm hoping someone can confirm the wiring I came up with for changing out the Trane thermostats with Honeywell.

System is 2-Stage Scroll HP with Honeywell TRUEZone HZ432.  The diagram shows the current wiring along with my 'proposed' wiring for the Honeywell T9s.  Honeywell support couldn't help with connecting the T9 to the HZ432.

Comment: Honeywell _couldn't_ help with the wiring, or _wouldn't_ help? I'd venture it was the latter...

Comment: Post your diagram as an answer and I'll +1 it

Comment: Glad you got this working! If you'll please take the [tour], you'll see that this is not a standard discussion forum where editing the _Answer_ into your _Question_ would be helpful. Instead, please roll back your question to ask _just_ the question, then write up your _answer_ in the box below labeled "Answer". Self-answered questions are not only perfectly acceptable, they're encouraged!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  Here is the final wiring diagram which seems to be working well.
[image: Working Wiring Diagram]